# Access application on another ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running two ec2 instances on the same private subnet. Instance1 has a public IP assigned to it as well. Instance2 is trying to access an application running on port 5000 of Instance1. How do I do this? I tried various resources but none seem to explain this clearly.

Comment: You're going to need to do several things, including opening up port 5000 on the EC node which you want accessible to the other EC node.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have done that. I am confused about what to add in the security groups

Comment: How will Instance2 be accessing Instance1 (i.e. what protocol)?  Check the AWS documentation, as it actually is rife with examples on how to do this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen All I am doing is a curl -X POST http://ip_addr_here:portnum/webhook command from Instance2

Comment: Then open TCP/IP on port 5000 for incoming, and then also add a rule for outgoing to all IP addresses.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it worked! Thanks :)

Comment: I think you'll find AWS to be way more user friendly than you might expect.